# What University Affiliation should I list on my paper?

Tags: affiliation

I wrote a paper with my colleagues at my alma mater, fresh graduated from my undergraduate degree. At that time I had no University Affiliation. Now I'm studying a Masters in ANOTHER university, should I put this new Institution as my Affiliation? or none?

Answer (score 2):

List your new (current) institute as the primary affiliation (i.e. the one that appears under your name on the front page). 
You can optionally add a footnote briefly mentioning the part of the work which was done while you were in your old institute.

Comment: I disagree. I would list my previous institute as my primary and note a different current university.